# Allow Only Barcode Scanner and Eliminate Keyboard Input

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, winforms

I have made a Windows Form application with a textbox which uses Barcode scanner to get any input value. I want user to use only Barcode Scanner to fill any value in it, and don't want to enter any input using my regular keyboard.

Since my Barcode works mimics as a keyboard, so disabling my regular keyboard will also disable my Barcode scanner to work.

I've searched manywhere to implement this, and found few answers were suggesting to add a Stopwatch/Timer to eliminiate all keypress which occurs within 50milliseconds, since Barcode can scan all values within 50 milliseconds, but no human can type faster than 50 miliseconds.

I also tried this way, but this fails when I randomly punches my fingers on keyboard keys, it reads out since some of keys fired within 50miliseconds.

Also tried below code but even this does not work as expected for me

```
private void rtBoxInput_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
}
```

Please suggest some good way to implement this?

Comment: my barcoder sends keys like someone was typing, so that wouldnt work in this senario.. it really does depend how it works.

Comment: Many scanners support two operation modes, HID (keyboard) mode and a direct/serial/OPOS compatible mode. For your requirements, I suggest to change the scanner operation mode to the direct mode, use the Microsoft POS for .NET Framework and attach to the scanner data event. Then you are completely independent from keyboard inputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic idea is to check:

if KeyUp and KeyDown events are fired of same keys and within specified time (say 17milliseconds), as this can be only done using Barcode scanner.

No one can trigger KeyDown and KeyUp event of same key within 17 milliseconds. For example it will take more than specified time for someone to Press and Release same key, however he can hit punch to keyboard that will push multiple keys all together and trigger their KeyDown and KeyUp events, but all no keys will have KeyUp and KeyDown events fired synchronously. So by this way you can detect whether input made by regular keyboard or barcode scanner.

Please have a look below:

```
public partial class BarcodeReader : Form
    {

        char cforKeyDown = '\0';
        int _lastKeystroke = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
        List<char> _barcode = new List<char>(1);
        bool UseKeyboard = false;
        public BarcodeReader()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void BarcodeReader_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(BarcodeReader_KeyDown);
            this.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(BarcodeReader_KeyUp);
        }
        private void BarcodeReader_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            // if keyboard input is allowed to read
            if (UseKeyboard && e.KeyData != Keys.Enter)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.KeyData.ToString());
            }

            /* check if keydown and keyup is not different
             * and keydown event is not fired again before the keyup event fired for the same key
             * and keydown is not null
             * Barcode never fired keydown event more than 1 time before the same key fired keyup event
             * Barcode generally finishes all events (like keydown > keypress > keyup) of single key at a time, if two different keys are pressed then it is with keyboard
             */
            if (cforKeyDown != (char)e.KeyCode || cforKeyDown == '\0')
            {
                cforKeyDown = '\0';
                _barcode.Clear();
                return;
            }

            // getting the time difference between 2 keys
            int elapsed = (DateTime.Now.Millisecond - _lastKeystroke);

            /*
             * Barcode scanner usually takes less than 17 milliseconds as per my Barcode reader to read , increase this if neccessary of your barcode scanner is slower
             * also assuming human can not type faster than 17 milliseconds
             */
            if (elapsed > 17)
                _barcode.Clear();

            // Do not push in array if Enter/Return is pressed, since it is not any Character that need to be read
            if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Return)
            {
                _barcode.Add((char)e.KeyData);
            }

            // Barcode scanner hits Enter/Return after reading barcode
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return && _barcode.Count > 0)
            {
                string BarCodeData = new String(_barcode.ToArray());
                if (!UseKeyboard)
                    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}", BarCodeData));
                _barcode.Clear();
            }

            // update the last key press strock time
            _lastKeystroke = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
        }

        private void BarcodeReader_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            //Debug.WriteLine("BarcodeReader_KeyDown : " + (char)e.KeyCode);
            cforKeyDown = (char)e.KeyCode;
        }
    }
```

Check Here.. [GitHub Link](https://github.com/royalbluemayank/BarcodeReader)

Comment: I am getting only the last 5 digits of 18 digits barcode.

Answer (score 0):

If your barcode mimics a keyboard - there is no way you can find which one is inputing text in your TextBox. Can your barcode scaner add some prefix to scanned code? If yes - I think this is a best option in combination with 50ms timer.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to handle your Barcode directly on your form using a KeyPress Event and disable your TextBox :

```
     private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
     {
        barcode = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            barcode += e.KeyChar;

            if (lastTime > new DateTime())
            {
                if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(lastTime).Milliseconds > 30)
                {
                    f1 = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    f1 = true;
                }
            }

            lastTime = DateTime.Now;

            /*

            Test your Barcode, and if it matches your criteria then change your TextBox text

            TextBox1.Text = barcode;

            */

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong");
        }
     }
```

Don't forgot to set Form1.KeyPreview = true and it should do the trick !